# FINDING STREET ADDRESS

Tags: google-maps, gis, reverse-geocoding, street-address

I have a question for the Google maps site. I am a private EMS dispatcher and we do not have expensive programs but I was hoping that there was a answer for me.

Does anyone one know of a way to find a street block range I have looked everywhere i could think of and cant find a way to place it.

as a example if someone tells me they on "highway 123 next to Smith Ave" is there a way to see it as 1400 block of HWY 123? I have tried google maps and so forth i may just not know where to look.

any help is great help
Thanks 
Chris

Comment: This isn't the place to ask, but that's an interesting question. I'm not sure why Google maps doesn't have this feature.

Comment: why do you need a block?

Comment: You might try the GIS Stack Exchange site with this question, too. But, you might like to know: I work for an address verification company ([SmartyStreets](http://www.smartystreets.com)) and while this data _is_ available, it's hard to format the results accurately for an end user to use and understand because ranges vary so much depending on the locale and perhaps the very whim of the postal service or city planners. I do know that we're currently designing an update to our API which will probably provide that information, so keep posted...

Answer (score 1):

On google maps right click on the street and select `what's here`. It should show either a range or an address.